# Firebase Database Query-get previous 20 key before specific key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do pagination. I want to get previous 20 key before my specific key.

For example:

[image]

When i say last key i mean its last key in my array list.Its not the last key of my databse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the specific key you can query the previous keys like this in javascript:

```
db.ref("YOUR parent node name").orderByKey().endAt("THE LAST KEY").limitToLast(20).once('value)
```

You can easily translate this code to any platform you are using.

Comment: It doesnt work   "reference.orderByKey().endAt(list.get(list.size()-1)).limitToLast(30);"  this is my code but still same

Comment: please add the complete code in your question where you are getting the data. What does list contains ?